# How to decorrelate residuals in r from the covariance matrix

Tags: r, model, covariance

I fit a geeglm model with clustered data and now I would like to decorrelate the residuals of the model in order to run model diagnostics.

I read that if I can obtain the covariance matrix of the residuals I can use the Cholesky decomposition to transform the residuals and thus decorrelate them.

How can I obtain this covariance matrix of residuals?

Comment: I believe the answer to this question depends on what working covariance structure you are using.  Can you clarify that?

Comment: Yes, I am using the ar1 covariance structure